# Given a binary tree of leaves with weights, find minimum weights for internal nodes (such that sum(weighti-weightj) is minimized for (i,j)∈E(T))

Tags: algorithms, trees, dynamic-programming, weighted-graphs

So this is a question within a bigger question for which I've reduced to this so far:

If I have a tree (phylogenetic) with known weights for leaves, how would I find the weights for all internal nodes such that the sum of the differences between the weights of two endpoints of edges is minimized?

- I.e. Given a tree $T$ with $n$ leaves with weights $D_1,\ldots,D_n$ respectively. Assign;

  a weight $D_u$ to each internal node $u = n+1,\ldots,2n-1$ such that
  $\sum_{(u,v) \in E(T)} (D_u-D_v)$ is minimized.

If it helps, it might be similar to the [Sankoff algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_phylogenetics) or so. Thanks!

Comment: You can use LaTeX to typeset mathematics, rather than doing it manually with various tricks (and non-tricks).  A couple of users have edited to show you how; we also have a [brief tutorial](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)

Comment: Do you mean the absolute value of the difference between $D_u$ and $D_v$ , $|D_u-D_v|$ instead of $D_u-D_v$? Minimizing (the sum of) the difference does not make sense, since $(v,u)$ is the same edge as $(u,v)$.